# Using Guard Live-reload with Susy

Tags: guard, susy

Has anyone used Guard Live-reload with Susy, here's the link to Guard: https://github.com/guard/guard.

I found where Guard is being used with Sass and Compass but so far I've not found where it's being used with Susy.

Any help will be appreciated

jrattling

Answer (score 0):

Since Susy is simply a Sass/Compass library, there is usually no need to integrate Susy directly with other build tools. Use the Sass/Compass-guard setup, install Susy like you would without guard ([see the docs](http://susydocs.oddbird.net)), and it should all just work.

Comment: Thanks for responding Eric, I really appreciate it. I've bailed out on guard and now I'm using grunt which I had working the other day and now grunt is broke and its giving me this error: >> File "_/components/sass/styles.scss" changed.
Running "compass:dev" (compass) task
LoadError on line ["54"] of /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb: cannot load such file -- breakpoint
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
Warning: ↑ Use --force to continue.

Comment: Sounds like you are requiring breakpoint somewhere, and don't have it installed properly?